# Call the variable from one file to other in python

Tags: python

1. I need to call the variable from other file1 to file2. But the variable in file1 will be updated during the run time of file2. So I need my program to be in wait or in a loop until the file1 variable is updated. For example, I tried below code.

```
#File1
x=None
#File2
import time
global y
y=None
def loop(y):
    from File1 import x
    print(x)
    global z
    z=x
    del x
    #print(y)
    return(z)

while y==None:
    print(y)
    time.sleep(3)
    if y == None:
        #print(y)
        loop(y)
        y=z
print(y)
```

2. Here, I made an infinite loop in file2 until the variable in file1 is changed from None to 1. But my loop is picking only the value that initially available in file1 and Even after I update the value in file1 during the runtime of file2, it's running with the same 'None' value in an infinite loop.

Can anyone help me to sort this issue or at least other methods I can follow.

Comment: Please, edit your question to put only code, here is a guide that explain why not post code as images. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question